Google ads app campaign Deferred Deeplink (DDL) is not recieving in GA4F sdk or Install Referrer - Android
I have implemented the GA4F SDK in our Android app to fetch Google ads app campaign Deferred Deeplink , and Google Ads support has confirmed that our setup, including the deep links, looks good. However, the functionality still isn’t working.
Issue - deeplink is not recieving in GA4F sdk or Install referrer callbacks.
Deeplinks pass validations in Google Playstore and Google ads deeplink validator
Still having issue
Sdk implementation Reference link -> https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/12373942?hl=en#zippy=%2Csteps-to-activate-ddl-in-the-gaf-sdk
Is there any configurations missing between Google ads and GA4F ?
